# DASH dropdowns and graph

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am having a problem in updating a map graph based on 3 dropdowns.

I have 3 dropdowns: one for country, one for district and one for category.

When I select 1 dropdown at a time I can see the results on the map.

But what I really want is to zoom in. So when I select country then district, I want to see the results in that particular district only.

Now, if I select a country from the dropdown and then select a category from the other dropdown, I see on the map the results of the whole country. It does not narrow down the search to just the category selected.

```
    dbc.Col([
            html.Label("Select Country: ", style={'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 15, 'color': 'white'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(className='scrollable-element div-for-dropdown Select-control VirtualizedSelectOption',
                         id='country_dropdown',
                         options=[{'label': str(c), 'value': c} for c in sorted(df['Country'].unique())],
                         multi=True,
                         placeholder="Select",
                         value=['United Kingdom'],
                         clearable=True,
                         style={'width': '100%', 'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 13, 'color': 'black', 'background-color': '#31302F', 'border': '0px solid black'}
                         ),

            html.Br(),

            html.Label("Select District: ", style={'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 15, 'color': 'white'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(className='scrollable-element div-for-dropdown Select-control VirtualizedSelectOption',
                         id='district_dropdown',
                         multi=True,
                         value=[],
                         clearable=True,
                         options=[{'label': str(d), 'value': d} for d in sorted(df['MainLocation'].unique())],
                         placeholder="Select",
                         style={'width': '100%', 'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 13, 'color': 'black', 'background-color': '#31302F', 'border': '0px solid black'}
                         ),
            html.Br(),

            html.Label("Select Category: ", style={'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 15, 'color': 'white'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(className='div-for-dropdown Select-control VirtualizedSelectOption',
                         id='category_dropdown',
                         multi=True,
                         value=[],
                         clearable=True,
                         options=[{'label': '(Select All)', 'value': 'all'}] + [{'label': str(cat), 'value': cat} for cat in sorted(df['Category'].unique())],
                         placeholder="Select",
                         style={'width': '100%', 'font-family': 'arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': 13, 'color': 'black', 'background-color': '#31302F', 'border': '0px solid black'}
                         )


`@app.callback(Output('map_graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('country_dropdown', 'value'),
               Input('category_dropdown', 'value'),
               Input('district_dropdown', 'value')])

def update_map_graph(chosen_country, chosen_category, chosen_district):
    df_sub = df[(df['Country'].isin(chosen_country)) |
                (df['Category'].isin(chosen_category)) |
                (df['MainLocation'].isin(chosen_district))]

    # Create figure
    locations = [go.Scattermapbox(
        lon=df_sub['Long'],
        lat=df_sub['Lat'],
        mode='markers',
        marker={'color': df_sub['Color'], 'size': 13, 'opacity': 0.5},
        unselected={'marker': {'opacity': 1}},
        selected={'marker': {'opacity': 0.5, 'size': 18}},
        hoverinfo='text',
        hovertext=df_sub['Hover']
    )]

    # Return figure
    return {
        'data': locations,
        'layout': go.Layout(
            autosize=True,
            margin=dict(l=0,
                        r=0,
                        t=0,
                        b=0),
            uirevision='foo',
            clickmode='event+select',
            hovermode='closest',
            hoverdistance=2,
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                bearing=0,
                style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-night-v1',
                center=dict(
                    lat=50.1109,
                    lon=8.6821
                ),
                pitch=0,
                zoom=5
            ),
        )
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you don't provide sample data,  so I've used UK hospital data
- create a **geopandas** data frame, so `total_bounds` can be used
- straight forward build drop downs progressively. get centre of geometry of any selections

```
import json
import numpy as np
import dash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import requests, io
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import plotly.express as px

# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that can be scattered
dfhos = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text
    ),
    sep="¬",
    engine="python",
)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    dfhos, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", hover_data=["County", "City", "Address1"]
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron"}, margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0}
)

# create a geo dataframe of hospitals
gdfhos = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data=dfhos,
    geometry=dfhos.apply(
        lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Longitude"], r["Latitude"]), axis=1
    ),
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)


# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Dropdown(
            id="County",
            options=[
                {"label": c, "value": c}
                for c in dfhos["County"].dropna().sort_values().unique()
            ],
            value=None,
        ),
        dash.dcc.Dropdown(id="City", value=None),
        dash.dcc.Dropdown(id="Address1", value=None),
        dash.dcc.Graph(
            id="map",
            figure=fig,
        ),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("map", "figure"),
        Output("City", "options"),
        Output("Address1", "options"),
    ],
    Input("County", "value"),
    Input("City", "value"),
    Input("Address1", "value"),
    State("map", "figure"),
)
def center_selection(county, city, address1, fig):
    city_out = []
    addr_out = []
    bb = gdfhos.geometry.total_bounds
    if county:
        bb = gdfhos.loc[gdfhos["County"].eq(county)].geometry.total_bounds
        city_out = [
            {"label": c, "value": c}
            for c in dfhos.loc[dfhos["County"].eq(county), "City"]
            .dropna()
            .sort_values()
            .unique()
        ]
    if county and city:
        bb = gdfhos.loc[
            gdfhos["County"].eq(county) & gdfhos["City"].eq(city)
        ].geometry.total_bounds
        addr_out = [
            {"label": c, "value": c}
            for c in dfhos.loc[
                dfhos["County"].eq(county) & dfhos["City"].eq(city), "OrganisationName"
            ]
            .dropna()
            .sort_values()
            .unique()
        ]

    return (
        go.Figure(fig).update_layout(
            mapbox={"center": {"lon": (bb[0] + bb[2]) / 2, "lat": (bb[1] + bb[3]) / 2}}
        ),
        city_out,
        addr_out,
    )


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. is it possible to do it without using geopandas ?

Comment: yes - just need to calc the bounding box which can be done in pandas. just more convenient to use geopandas capability